# Exception Handling In Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework, exception, zend-framework2

I have tried using try catch in my code but it's not catching any exceptions.

```
{           
   $this->mapper->DeletePassssedAndImages($langcode."_topic",$id,$type,$langcode);
}
catch ( \Exception $exc )
{
    echo "hi";
    exit;
);
```

Its not going to the catch block even if i throw an exception manually.

Comment: can you show your code, what you have tried till now

Comment: There's no "try" in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zend Framework throw the Exceptions more specific. So, you will know from where the error come from.
Example, in `Zend\ServiceManager` there are a few exceptions

```
Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\CircularDependencyFoundException
Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\CircularReferenceException
Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\InvalidArgumentException
Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\InvalidServiceNameException
Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\RuntimeException
Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotCreatedException
Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException
```

You can make handler based on Exception throwed. But you can use `try catch` block like this to handle Exception.

```
try {

} catch \Exception ($e) {

}
```

Because all of those exceptions extends from `\Exception`

Comment: try
  {
   
            $this->mapper->DeletePassssedAndImages($langcode."_topic",$id,$type,$langcode);
  }
  catch ( \Exception $exc )
  {
            echo "hi";
            exit;
   $ViewModel = $mvcEvent->getViewModel();
   $ViewModel->setTemplate( 'layout/error-layout' );
   $content = new ViewModel();
   $content->setTemplate( 'error/503' );
   $ViewModel->setVariable(
    'content', $serviceManager->get( 'ViewRenderer' )->render( $content )
   );
   exit( $serviceManager->get( 'ViewRenderer' )->render( $ViewModel ) );
  }

Comment: i have added the code above what u suggested is not working

Comment: If `\Exception` catched, it will just display **hi**. Because you put `exit` after `echo 'hi'`

Comment: ofcourse but it didnt print hi thats the problem,pls help me

Comment: is there any exception throwed @SivaKamath?